# Android Studio 2.2.3 Instant Run is not an Option

Tags: android, android-studio, android-instant-run, instant-run

I have a new install of Android Studio and I'm starting my first project. I was looking for ways to speed up my deploy/test development cycle when I read that I already should have the **Instant Run** feature enabled.

I double checked a few settings:

- `Tools->Android->Enable ADB Integration` is checked
- `File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Instant Run` **Enable Instant Run...** is checked, along with **Restart activity on code changes** and **Show Toasts in the running app...**
- My emulator is a Nexus 5, API 24
- The Android gradle plugin is defined as: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'`
- The project **minSdkVersion** is 16 and **targetSdkVersion** is 25

And yet, the Instant Run icons do not appear on my Run configurations and redeploying involves restarting the whole app and takes about a minute. Some possibilities for the error:

- I read that DDMS must be disabled for Instant Run to work in another question. I don't know if that's true since I don't see it mentioned in the official documentation, but if I go to the **Android Device Monitor** I see a DDMS button that cannot be uncheked.
- Anticipating a future integration, I enabled this project to allow for C++ code to be integrated. I'm not sure if that plays a part.

Comment: That's true. If Android Device Monitor is open, then Enable ADB Integration will be disable automatically

Comment: I think apps with native part are not Instant run compatible. Try without c++ intergation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was stopped on two different fronts.

1. I anticipated using a C++ library in the future for this project and created with C support setup. Use of this type of native library will prevent Instant Run from working.
2. I wanted to take advantage of the latest Java 8 features, in this case Lambda expressions and Streams. Unfortunately this requires use of the **jacktoolchain** option which will prevent Instant Run from working. In general, I found these features to be buggy anyways so I opted to return Java 1.7 (insert sad-face here) and gain the benefit of being able to do rapid-deployments.

Because the new features of Java 8 are so powerful, I hope they are made available to developers sooner rather than later. One option that I have not explored is using Zero Turnaround's hot swap system with Java 8 and I will look into that.

For those that are coming here to diagnose Instant Run problems, know that checking the "Show Instant Run status notifications" in `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run` might provide valuable clues as to problems with this feature (Android Studio 2.2)

Answer (score 1):

Check if `minSdkVersion` is set to at least 15 and `Android plugin for Gradle version` at least to 2.0.0.

You can check all the details here

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run

Comment: sorry, that was already checked. I'll update my question to reflect that